# Django-registration, template

Tags: python, django

where can I find good templates for django-registration? I've found one, but the activation isn't work properly - when user click on activation link he gets:

> Hello !
>   Check your e-mail to confirm registration. 7 days left.

Instead of ~"Activation succesfull/fail".

Answer (score 18):

Some templates can be found here: http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/

```
$ tree
.
|-- [            981]  base.html
|-- [             89]  index.html
`-- [            544]  registration
    |-- [            287]  activate.html
    |-- [            221]  activation_email.txt
    |-- [             67]  activation_email_subject.txt
    |-- [            459]  login.html
    |-- [            110]  logout.html
    |-- [            116]  password_change_done.html
    |-- [            192]  password_change_form.html
    |-- [            193]  password_reset_complete.html
    |-- [            283]  password_reset_confirm.html
    |-- [            153]  password_reset_done.html
    |-- [            215]  password_reset_email.html
    |-- [            192]  password_reset_form.html
    |-- [            146]  registration_complete.html
    `-- [            192]  registration_form.html
```

Answer (score 14):

I found the templates here to be a good starting point:

https://github.com/yourcelf/django-registration-defaults

(Note that you need to a base.html for them to include)

Answer (score 2):

[the djen of django book](http://agiliq.com/books/djenofdjango/chapter5.html#reusable-apps) has some templates for django-registration with some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of Django-registration-redux. Current version is 1.4. Also go to [this](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/tree/master/registration/templates/registration) link and download django-registration app manually. After its downloaded just drag drop your templates from templates/registration to your templates/registration. Check again an post the situation after these steps.